# laravel mail how to properly implement into the system

Tags: php, laravel, email

So I am trying to implement a command that notifies all users that are subscribes to an event with command that does an check every day. I was reading [Laravel mail docs 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail) so there example is about order system where they send the mail with this peace of code

```
foreach (['taylor@example.com', 'dries@example.com'] as $recipient) {
    Mail::to($recipient)->send(new OrderShipped($order));
}
```

what as it looks takes the email of of the loop and then send an email toward that adress.
So I made a mail class `php artisan make:mail NotifyUserOfEvents`
 and where I made this code

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Event;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NotifyUserOfEvents extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

protected $event;

public function __construct(Event $event)
{
    $this->event = $event;
}

public function build()
{
    return $this->view('mails.NotifyUserOfEvents')
        ->with([
            'name' => $this->event->name,
            'date' => $this->event->settings->start_date,
        ]);
}
}
```

but when I try to call this class with this function

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Event;
use App\RegistrationEvents;
use App\User;
use Carbon\Carbon; 
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class NotifyUsersForEvents extends Command
{
protected $signature = 'NotifyUsersForEvents';

protected $description = 'Notify the user for the event. test run with -> php artisan schedule:run';

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function handle()
{
    Log::debug('this works every minute');

    $events = Event::query()
        ->with('settings')
        ->has('settings')
        ->get();

    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $week = Carbon::now()->addWeek();
        $sixDays = $week->copy()->subDay();
        if (Carbon::create($event->settings->date_start)->between($week, $sixDays)) {
            $subscriptions = RegistrationEvents::query()
                ->where('event_id', $event->id)
                ->get();
            foreach ($subscriptions as $subscription) {
                var_dump($subscription->user_id);
                $user = User::findOrFail($subscription->user_id);

                Mail::to($user->email)->send($event);
                var_dump($user->email);
            }
        }
    }

  }
}
```

it returns this error:   `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in` so do I need to change the way I call the mail class or do I need to add something to the Event Model?

also the event.php

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Event extends Model implements Mailable
{
use SoftDeletes;

public function settings(){

    return $this->hasOne('App\EventSettings', 'event_id');

}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You must pass to `send` function an object of your `NotifyUserOfEvents`, not an `Event` object.

Try this:

`Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NotifyUserOfEvents($event));`

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this line:

```
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Event($event));
```

you are creating a new `Event` passing to the constructor another `Event`... you probably never define a constructor that accept as first parameter an `Event`...
But despite that, what's the sense of doing this? To `Mail::send` you have to pass a `Mailable`, not an event, and i'm pretty sure you don't need a new event, so i believe you would want to do something like this:

```
use App\Mail\NotifyUserOfEvents; // or whatever namespace you have to the mail
Mail::to($user->email)->send(new NotifyUserOfEvents($event));
```

Comment: then I get another error `Class App\Event contains 8 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable::send, Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable::queue, Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailable::later, ...)`  then it generates functions like this `public function send($mailer)
    {
        // TODO: Implement send() method.
    }`  So for instance what do i need to implement in the `send()` functions

Comment: @HashtagForgotName be sure to have `use App\Models\Events` (so your model) in NotifyUserOfEvents, otherwise Laravel will use the alias of Event, which is another whole world

Comment: @HashtagForgotName to be sure, please post the whole file, with all the "use ..." and not just the class itself

Comment: update the post also I hade `app/Event` imported the idea im using suggest that I generate the `Class must be declared abstract or implement methods 'bcc', 'cc', 'to', 'later', 'locale', 'mailer', 'queue', 'send'` what will generate thos functions but then it will error on those functions

Comment: @HashtagForgotName Event doesn't have to implements Mailable

Answer (score 0):

```
$user   = User::find($id);
$email  = $user->email;
if(Helper::isValidEmail($email))
                    {
                        Mail::send('emails.applicant_reference', 
$emailParameters, function($message) use ($email, $name, $subject){
                            $message->to($email, $name)
                            ->subject($subject);
                        });
```

Answer (score -1):

$applicantName = null;
$subject = " Application received for ".$applicantName;
                        $emailParameters = ["applicantName" => $applicantName, "proposerName" => $proposerName, "seconderName" => $seconderName];
                            try
                            {

```
                                Mail::send('emails.application', $emailParameters, function($message) use ($applicantName, $subject){
                                    $message->to(['test@gmail.com','test@gamil.com'], " Test Email Function ")
                                    ->subject($subject);
                                });


                        } catch (Exception $ex){ Log::error("UserController".$ex->getMessage());

                    }
```